# Jenkins build + Docker + auto deployment

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

This is what we need:

1. grab code from a github repo >> download to jenkins >> Build

2. On successful build, spawn a/multiple docker tomcat container and deploy the code there.

**we have a custom tomcat image(built from a valid dockerfile). I came to know about lots of jenkins docker-plugin but unable to understand the flow on how to implement.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

To build and so on take a look at docker-py. So you needn't extra plugin to start a container.

http://docker-py.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/

Regards
Gino

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11814846)

Comment: The link won't change because it is referred to the stable version.